# Excel VBA- Moving Past Hidden Cells in a Filtered Column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code where I need to copy data from filtered cells in Column E to Column A. The filter is done by a loop therefore data is displayed one by one. All I need to do is to directly go down one cell from my active cell but the problem is, I have no idea what cell value is directly below and if I use offset, excel just copies the next hidden cell.

Here is a brief overview of how the macro works:

First Cell is E1(header and active cell) next cell is E102(value I have to copy to A102).

Then a loop activates, first cell is E1 then next cell is E365(copy to A365).
and so on...

The next value is also unpredictable therefore I cannot call the value.

I've tried the following code but send keys doesn't seem to work

```
Cells.Find(What:="Header", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Range("A1").Select

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}"

Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Range("A1").Select
Selection.Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to work with the Areas property but you have a special case where you only require the second cell.

```
'assume column E has been filtered
With Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
    With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("E:E"))
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Offset(0, -4) = _
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Value
        End With
    End With
End With
```

I don't know why your code says .Offset(0, -3) since column A is a -4 offset from column E.

Comment: I've tried your code but it doesn't seem to work, I don't know which part it went wrong but I tweaked this portion With Worksheets("sheet1") to With Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally pressed enter while editing, fixed it now. The value in A remains constant even with the code in the loop.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Fixed above.